# want to drop columns in panda but should not show error if column already present

Tags: pandas

I want to drop columns in pandas but if the columns are not present it shows an error , i want it to not show an error and drop remaining columns which are present.Is there  a function or any method that will help me achieve that.

Answer (score 10):

Use parameter `errors='ignore'` in [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

> **errors** : {'ignore', 'raise'}, default 'raise'
>   If 'ignore', suppress error and only existing labels are dropped.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','b','c'],
    'B': list(range(3))
})
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  0
1  b  1
2  c  2

df = df.drop(['B','C'], errors='ignore', axis=1)
print (df)
   A
0  a
1  b
2  c
```